# How to get the nodes inner text in java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, dom, xpath

I have a string of XML format. As shown below:

```
<gt>
    <st>sample1</st>
    <tt>sample2</tt>                    
    <tt>sample3</tt>
</gt>
```

I need to get the  node value in Java script file. How can I get the value?

Comment: @NiftyDude Thanks for ur response. I tried using this command but no result. $(xml).find("st").text();

Comment: so you are using jQuery?

Comment: @NiftyDude yes I am trying to use Jquery.It is not working. If XPath will work, I am ready to use. Thanks.

Comment: Hm ok, what is `xml` in `$(xml).find()...` ?

Comment: can you try something like http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/xml-to-json/ ? and then play with json as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var xml = "<gt><st>sample1</st><tt>sample2</tt><tt>sample3</tt></gt>",
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
    $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
    $st = $xml.find( "st" );

alert( $st.text() );
```

See the [js fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/3Rtnd/1/)

Comment: the reason generally people post fiddle link is others can test it quickly and also try changing it as per requirement. Sorry, If i accidentally broke any stackoverflow rule

Comment: I post demos as well, but not just links. the update is fine.

Comment: @Kshitij $.parseXML() throwing error like "Is not a function". Do I need to add any Java script files?

Comment: i hope you have imported jquery core .js file.. If not you will need to

Comment: heres the link to download latest jquery library, use the minified version as it is compressed - http://blog.jquery.com/2012/03/21/jquery-1-7-2-released/

Comment: can you share your code...proabably we can identity the error better...just edit your question above and add the code where you are importing the jquery*.js and the part where function is called.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`.parseXML()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/).

```
var xmldom = $.parseXML('<gt><st>sample1</st><tt>sample2</tt><tt>sample3</tt></gt>');

console.log($(xmldom).find('gt *'));
```

This will find all nodes under `<gt>`.

Comment: $.parseXML() throwing error like "Is not a function". Do I need to add any Java script files?